# splitting up text with a regular expression in google app script (documentApp) with findText

Tags: regex, google-apps-script

In a google doc (not a spreadsheet) I have a wall of text that looks like

```
 °foo bar header°foo bar bat paragraph°and another paragraph°and yet an other paragraph°and so on
```

and I want to split up the text into paragraphs.

So I would like to get the text between the ° chars with help of a regexp. I would like to use

```
     var rangeElement = body.findText("°([^°]*)°");
```

but that regexp makes google docs go "Service unavailable: Docs". Using a regexp like `"°.?°"` alleviates that problem, but does not isolate the text I want.

What is a regexp that would work? How can I proceed to process the substring from within the `(` and `)`?

Comment: Try `var rx = /°([^°]*)/g;` and then `while (m=rx.exec(doc.getBody().getText())) {
    Logger.log("Matched: " + m[1]);
  }`

Comment: DocumentApp does not have a method exec for regular expressions, strings or text  in general, for any of its classes. The methods that do regular expressions are findText and replaceText.

Comment: Wrong. You may use JavaScript RegExp the way I showed in my first comment. Looks like you have not even tried what I  suggested (copied from my Google script).

Comment: gee, I did try. :-) It gives me these error:
`TypeError: Cannot find function exec in object /°([^°]*)/g.`

Comment: Edit the question to show how you tried that. It worked without issues in my script.

Comment: Thank you for insisting - I messed up the regex by putting quotes around it. I suggest you properly answer the question with his block of code, so I can accept it.

`var rx = /°([^°]*)/g;
  while (m=rx.exec(body.getText())) {
    Logger.log("Matched: " + m[1]);
}`

Comment: maybe you should show the script that wraps the regex. Everyone is not an expert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all (multiple) matches, you can leverage the JavaScript `RegExp` witha `g` (global) modifier.

```
var rx = /°([^°]*)/g;
while (m=rx.exec(doc.getBody().getText())) { 
    Logger.log("Matched: " + m[1]);
}
```

The `/°([^°]*)/g` is a *regex literal notation* (mind there should be no quotes around it), where `/` are regex delimiters, `°([^°]*)` is the pattern matching `°` symbol and then capturing into Group 1 any 0 or more chars other than `°` (`([^°]*)`) any number of times (`g`).

To actually match all the occurrences, you need to call `RegExp#exec` multiple times and grab Group 1 value (`m[1]`).

[image]

Comment: hello, is it possible to use this method for range of values. If so, how to do it?